# How do I escape single quotes with perl interpreter?

Tags: perl, bash

How do I escape the single qoutes in my bash expression `find . | xargs perl -pi -e 's/'conflicts' => '',//g'`? I want to replace the string 'conflicts' => '', in my files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't directly escape it within single quotes, so to get a single quote you need to do something like:

```
$ echo 'i'\''m a string with a single quote'
i'm a string with a single quote
```

This ends the quoted part, escapes a single quote as it would appear outside of quotes, and then begins the quoting again. The result will still be one argument.

Answer (score 14):

FatalError and gpojd have both given good solutions. I'll round this out with one other option:

```
find . | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\x27conflicts\x27 => \x27\x27,//g'
```

This works because in Perl, the `s/.../.../` notation supports backslash-escapes. `\x27` is a hexadecimal escape (`'` being U+0027).

Answer (score 5):

Use double quotes around your code instead:

```
find . | xargs perl -pi -e "s/'conflicts' => '',//g"
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, since quite a few characters commonly used in Perl code (most notably `!`) have a special meaning to bash even inside double quotes.

Comment: The only time I would use `"` instead of `'` is on Windows, where the single quotes don't work.