# Perl extract group with lookbehind from different line

Tags: regex, perl

I've tried web search and have read several answers on stackexchange, still cannot grasp why command does not extract anything. At the end I want to extract group with lookbehind from different line, e.g. from

```
Code>TEST1<Code Code2>best<Code2
Code>test2<Code
Type>false<Type
```

by finding needed key between `Type` and extracting first `Code` above the finding, so it case above to get `test2`. But I cannot succeed to extract even something from multiple lines, i.e.

`perl -lne 'print $1,"_",$2 if /Code>(.*)<Code[\s\S\n]*?Type>(.*)<Type/'<test.txt` prints nothing.
I've played with removing `ln` parameters and adding/removing greedy `?` and trying just `.` in place of `[\s\S\n]`.

`perl -lne 'print $1,"_",$2 if /Code>(.*)<Code[\s\S\n]*?Code2>(.*)<Code2/'<test.txt`
 gives `TEST1_best` so same line extraction works.

What am I missing? Can what I want be done in one line of command?

Comment: `-n` causes the code to be run for every line, so `$_` only contains one line. At the very least, you'll need `-0777` to make `-n` read the whole file at once.

Comment: @ikegami, I've tried to remove `-n`, what is `-0777` - other parameter?

Comment: If you leave out `-n`, you're left with a program that doesn't read anything at all!

Comment: Like I said, it causes `-n` (well, technically, any `readline` aka `<>` aka `<$fh>` aka `<FH>`) to read the whole file at once instead of one line at a time.

Comment: @ikegami, after reading about perl more, I now imagine you laughed writing your second comment and I want to laugh myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command answers your question: it collects all values contained in a `Code>...<Code` pattern, if they are followed by a `Type>...<Type` pattern (with potentially other patterns in between, but no other occurrences of `Code>...<Code` in between):

```
perl -lne 's/^.*?(?=Code>)//s; for (split /Code>/) { print qq($1:$2\n) if /(.*?)<Code.*?Type>(.*?)<Type/s }' -0777 <test.txt
```

If e.g. `test.txt` contains the following lines,

```
Code>test4<Code Type>false<Type
Code>test3<Code
Type>true<Type
Code>TEST1<Code Code2>best<Code2
Code>test2<Code
Type>false<Type
```

then the command will collect the following value pairs:

```
test4:false
test3:true
test2:false
```

***Edited on 04/08/2019, 17:38 CEST***  I edited the command to remove the "header part" of the file (the part before the first occurrence of `Code>`), as it might - by some error of the file's editor - contain a closing tag `<Code` which had not been opened with `Code>` but instead with a typo like e.g. `Cde>`. My assumption was that the complete file was "syntactically correct" in the sense that it consists of elements of type `/(\w+)>.*?<\1/`, separated by whitespace (including newlines). For files which do not conform to this syntax, the statement was not waterproof.

Comment: thank you. I tried to google `perl -0777 option` but looks like nothing relevant in top results. Where can I read about perl specifics? e.g. also seems to be different info about escaping single quote, it's IMHO difficult to find sure info. Part of the reason I'm asking is that I need to tailor your code to other searches, and e.g. changing `Code>` with `Cod>` prints start of first line of file, I prefer it find nothing obviously.

Comment: o, for single quote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700565/how-do-i-escape-single-quotes-with-perl-interpreter accepted answer does not produce error for your code, whereas changing to double quotes does produce error. actually trying to add signle quote lead me to my finding about finding something instead of nothing.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov The option `-0` for changing the file separator when reading lines is described where I would expect it: in the standard `perlrun` docu. It also describes that `-0777` is used widely for "slurp mode" (i.e. reading the whole file with one readline call).

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov So the particular question of this SO is answered, and now you want to extend the method to other or more complex cases. I would therefore recommend you to work with a Perl file instead of the command line. In particularly, you can then avoid all your "single quote" hassle.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov I changed the command to remove the "header" part before the first occurrence of a `Code>` keyword. My assumption was that the file is "syntactically correct", as described in the note above.

Comment: thank you. it's for log files - they may contain tags in question, may not contain at all and may contain anything in intermittent places, looks like I better mention such things in question. As for full perl file suggestion, I need to run the code in different places, it's much easier to copy line to command prompt.

Comment: I now have read and understand all your code, except two minor: 1) why second `s` `operator` after `//`? 2) as I've read perl likes concise, why -nle '' -0777, not -0777ne ''?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov 1) The second `s` modifier is necessary since the `Type` token which follows the `Code` token may appear on a subsequent line. Therefore, the `.` in `.*?` must be allowed to be a newline character as well. 2) You are right, this should work as well.

Comment: beg your pardon, again on second s. I've read `https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html` with `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer` and no info what `msixpodualngcer` is (and web search did not help me). If it's a place for options, then I did not see `s` as available option, How does it work?

Comment: `msixpodualngcer` is the complete set of available regex modifiers, each modifier is a single letter. To any regex you may add arbitrary many modifiers. Now read the meaning of `s` in https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, using progressive matching and embedded code

```
perl -lne 'while (/\b(?:Code>(.*?)<Code(?{$c=$1})|Type>(.*?)<Type(?{print qq($c:$2\n) if defined $c;undef $c}))\b/g){}' -0777 <test.txt
```

Explanations:

- Basically, the expression finds occurrences of `Code>(.*?)<Code` or `Type>(.*)<Type`. This gives the basic form of an alternation in an unnamed grouping expression: `(?:Code>(.*?)<Code|Type>(.*?)<Type)`.
- The word boundary assertions `\b` around the group ensure that the keywords `Code`and `Type` are matched, but not e.g. `Code2` or `TType`.
- The modifier `g` ensures progressive application of the regular expression on the string. Since I want to extract the result inside of the expression itself, I place the regex in an empty loop, i.e. `while (/.../g) {}`.
- You suppose a grammar rule `Code ⟶ Type`, i.e. you look for occurrences of a `Type` token following a `Code` token. For this, a `Code` token is memorized in a variable `$c` with the code expression `(?{$c=$1})`. If a `Type` token is found, it is considered a match only if formerly a `Code` token has been found, indicated by the fact that the variable `$c` is defined. In any case, if a `Type` token has been found, the variable `$c` will be `undef`d to prepare it for the next search. This gives the code evaluation `(${print qq($c:$2\n) if defined $c;undef $c;})` in the `Type` branch of the regular expression.
- Note that the captures of the `Code>(.*?)<Code` and `Type>(.*?)<Type` tokens may be the empty string. This is why I am working with `undef $c` and `if defined $c` instead of the simpler `$c=''` and `if $c`.

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd', by gnu sed;

```
sed -Ez 's/.*Code>(\w+)<Code\sType>\w*<Type.*/\1/' d
```

Perl

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{undef $/} /Code>(\w+)<Code\nType>\w*<Type/; print $1' d
```